# Unable to right click on the cmd windows prompt

Tags: cmd.exe

I am unable to right click on the cmd windows prompt in order to paste something there. How can I fix this problem?
  Thanks

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 2):

> ### [CMD Shell](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-cmd.html)
>
> **In Windows 10 the standard Ctrl-X & Ctrl-C shortcuts are supported.**
>
> For earlier versions of Windows you can enable QuickEdit cut and paste
>   at the Command Prompt as follows:
>
> Activate the control menu at the top left of the current cmd window,
>   go to Properties, Options tab and then tick against QuickEdit Mode.
>   Now you can select text with the mouse and hit Enter (or right click)
>   to copy it to the clipboard. Paste anywhere using Control+V (or Right
>   Click) or via the menu.
>
> ESC will cancel any selection and return to editing mode. When copying
>   between windows, you need one click to select the window and a second
>   click to paste.
>
> <sub>[source](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-cmd.html)</sub>

---

### Windows 10

*Right-click* on the command prompt window *title bar*, select **Properties**, from **Options**, be sure to check the **Insert Mode** option to have the **Paste** option available from the command prompt with a *right-click*. Optionally, if you also select the **QuickEdit Mode** and have it *checked*, when you *right-click* in the command window, it'll paste what you have copied without needing to select the paste option.

[image]
[image]

---

### Other Windows Versions

You will basically follow the same instructions as above on other versions of Windows for the cmd.exe **properties** but the **Edit Options** location will look a little different, but *checking* the **Insert Mode** and **Quick Edit** options will give you the same results/functionality.

[image]

Comment: You can also left-click on the Titelbar icon to open the system menu.